# How to add a Google Map to a html page correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Recently I tried to add a google map to a web page by using Google API, but was unable to do it. How can I fix this? I need helps to fix this problem.
This can be run as a html file, but when I tried with my local server, the script is unable to load.

```
<script>
  function avMap(){
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('map1');
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(6.949707,80.1831939);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: mapCenter,
        zoom:11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //SATELLITE, HYBRID, TERRAIN
    };
    var mapAv = new google.maps.Map(myCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapCenter,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            draggable: false
        });
    marker1.setMap(mapAv);
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: 6.4692368, lng: 80.5755751},
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            draggable: false
        });
    marker2.setMap(mapAv);
    //info-window
    var avNote = "<p>"+"Avissawella is the most beautiful area in Sabaragamuwa/Western border."+" "+"For more details, please visit"+
    " "+"<a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avissawella'"+ "target='_blank'>"+"this link"+"</a>";
    var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: avNote,
        maxWidth:200
    });
    infoWin.open(mapAv, marker1);   
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=avMap"></script>
```

Comment: where is your api key?

Comment: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
`
please rever to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: Is API key required for adding a map to the server? I can open it correctly as a local file, The problem occurs only when I used to run it from a remote or local server.

Comment: API keys are now required.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `async defer` on your script include.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=avMap"></script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=avMap" async defer></script>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rj32gstg/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script>
  function avMap() {
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('map1');
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(6.949707, 80.1831939);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: mapCenter,
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //SATELLITE, HYBRID, TERRAIN
    };
    var mapAv = new google.maps.Map(myCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: mapCenter,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
      draggable: false
    });
    marker1.setMap(mapAv);
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: 6.4692368,
        lng: 80.5755751
      },
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      draggable: false
    });
    marker2.setMap(mapAv);
    //info-window
    var avNote = "<p>" + "Avissawella is the most beautiful area in Sabaragamuwa/Western border." + " " + "For more details, please visit" +
      " " + "<a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avissawella'" + "target='_blank'>" + "this link" + "</a>";
    var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: avNote,
      maxWidth: 200
    });
    infoWin.open(mapAv, marker1);
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=avMap" async defer></script>
<div id="map1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks dear. This code snippet makes an error message :

    Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

I searched about API keys. What is the difference between normal API key and premium one? What should I select?

Comment: API keys are now required (SO and jsfiddle are grandfathered for keyless access).  You should get a normal API key unless you require a premium key (and/or want to pay for it).

Comment: If this answered your original question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)